# Kubernetes ud615 newbie secure-monolith.yaml `error validating data`?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm a Kubernetes newbie trying to follow along with the Udacity tutorial class linked on the Kubernetes website.

I execute

```
kubectl create -f pods/secure-monolith.yaml
```

That is referencing this official yaml file: https://github.com/udacity/ud615/blob/master/kubernetes/pods/secure-monolith.yaml

I get this error:

```
error: error validating "pods/secure-monolith.yaml": error validating data: unknown object type schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"", Version:"v1", Kind:"Pod"}; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

FYI, the official lesson link is here: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud615/lessons/7824962412/concepts/81991020770923

My first guess is that the provided yaml is out of date and incompatible with the current Kubernetes. Is this right? How can I fix/update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After correct kubectl version (Same with server version)**, then the issue is fixed, see:

```
$ kubectl create -f config.yml
configmap "test-cfg" created

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", ...
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", ...
```

*This is the case before modification*:

```
$ kubectl create -f config.yml
error: error validating "config.yml": error validating data: unknown object type schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"", Version:"v1", Kind:"ConfigMap"}; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8",...
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7",...
```

**In general, we should used same version for kubectl and kubernetes.**

Comment: You are right. Kubernetes 1.8 was released a while ago, yet Minikube still only supports Kubernetes 1.7. It looks like Minikube is about to get 1.8 support. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem but with a much simpler example.

Here's my yaml:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80`

The command `kubectl create -f pod-nginx.yaml` returns:

`error: error validating "pod-nginx.yaml": error validating data: unknown object type schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"", Version:"v1", Kind:"Pod"}; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

As the error says, I am able to override it but I am still at a loss as to the cause of the original issue.

Local versions:

- `Ubuntu 16.04`
- `minikube version: v0.22.2`
- `kubectl version: 1.8`

Thanks in advance!